# Copiar lista simplesmente encadeada em C

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados

Olá, pessoal, preciso de ajuda para copiar uma lista simplesmente encadeada de trás pra frente. Por exemplo, se a lista original é 1->2->3->null, preciso que ela passe a ser 3->2->1->null.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int bool;
enum { false, true };

// elemento da lista
typedef struct estr {
    char letra;
    struct estr *prox;
} NO;

typedef struct {
    NO *inicio;
} LISTA;

void inicializarLista(LISTA *l) {
    l->inicio = NULL;
}

void criarLista(LISTA *l, char plvr[]) {
    NO *ult = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plvr); i++) {
        NO *novo = (NO *) malloc(sizeof(NO));
        novo->letra = plvr[i];
        novo->prox = NULL;
        if (ult) {
            ult->prox = novo;
        } else {
            l->inicio = novo;
        }
        ult = novo;
    }
}

void imprimirLista(LISTA l) {
    NO *p = l.inicio;
    while(p) {
        printf("%c", p->letra);
        p = p->prox;
    }
}

LISTA* clonarLista(LISTA* l){
  NO novo = NULL;
  LISTA* resp = novo; //inicializar lista resp
  while(l){
    novo = (NO *) malloc(sizeof(NO));
    novo->letra = l->letra;
    novo->prox = NULL;
    l = l->prox;
  }
  return resp;
}

void inverter(LISTA* resp){
  NO* ant = NULL;
  NO* atual = //inicio da lista resp
  NO* seg; //seguinte
  while (atual){
    seg = atual->prox;  
    atual->prox = ant;   
    ant = atual;
    atual = atual->prox;
    }
    //inicio da lista resp = ant;
}

int main() {
    LISTA l;
    LISTA resp;
    inicializarLista(&l);
    inicializarLista(resp);
    char palavra[] = "caio";
    criarLista(&l, palavra);
    inverter(&resp)
    imprimirLista(resp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função de inverter tem uma variável com o valor em aberto:

```
NO* atual = //inicio da lista resp
```

O que gera um erro de sintaxe pois falta o valor e o `;`. Assim como a lógica não faz o pretendido. Em vez disso poderá reconstruir a lista adicionando os nós à cabeça o que irá fazer a inversão:

```
void inverter(LISTA* resp){

    NO* atual = resp->inicio;

    //redefinir a lista para começar vazia, sendo que o ponteiro atual ainda 
    //aponta para os seus elementos
    resp->inicio = NULL; 

    while (atual){ //enquanto tiver nós
        NO* corrente = atual; //guardar o nó corrente
        atual = atual->prox; //avançar o nó atual


        corrente->prox = resp->inicio; //fazer o prox do corrente ser o 1 da lista invertida
        resp->inicio = corrente; //o inicio passa a ser este ultimo nó
    }
}
```

A função de impressão de lista deve de receber um ponteiro, igual ao que as outras funções recebem, ficando então:

```
void imprimirLista(LISTA *l) { //agora com *l
    NO *p = l->inicio; //agora com ->
    while(p) {
        printf("%c", p->letra);
        p = p->prox;
    }
}
```

O que faz o `main` passar a ser diferente. E o `main` que tinha, invertia uma lista que não tinha valor atribuído, a lista `resp`, assim como lhe faltava um `&`. Deveria então ficar assim:

```
int main() {
    LISTA l;
    LISTA resp;
    inicializarLista(&l);
    inicializarLista(&resp); //agora com &
    char palavra[] = "caio";
    criarLista(&l, palavra);
    inverter(&l); //inverter o l que é o que tem a palavra
    imprimirLista(&l); //imprimir o que foi invertido

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**:

Para inverter um clone da lista original é necessário primeiro acertar a função de clonagem que tem algumas coisas erradas:

- `NO novo = NULL;` é uma inicialização inválida a menos que seja um ponteiro
- `novo->letra = l->letra;` l é do tipo `LISTA` logo apenas tem o campo `inicio` e não o campo `letra` e o mesmo acontece em `while(l)` que não é util para a navegação
- Falta a construção dos `prox` dos novos nós, para que a lista fique com todos os elementos ligados

Corrigindo tudo ficamos com:

```
LISTA* clonarLista(LISTA* l){
  LISTA* resp = malloc(sizeof(LISTA)); 

  NO *corrente = l->inicio;
  NO *anterior = NULL; //utilizar um nó anterior para ligar os vários elementos

  while(corrente){ //agora com corrente em vez de l
    NO *novo = (NO *) malloc(sizeof(NO));
    novo->letra = corrente->letra;
    novo->prox = NULL;

    if (anterior == NULL){ //se é o primeiro fica no inicio da nova lista
        resp->inicio = novo;
    }
    else { //se não é o primeiro liga o anterior a este pelo prox
        anterior->prox = corrente;
    }

    anterior = novo;
    corrente = corrente->prox;
  }

  return resp;
}
```

Para que o `main` inverta uma copia em vez do original podemos alterar para:

```
int main() {
    LISTA l;
    inicializarLista(&l);
    char palavra[] = "caio";
    criarLista(&l, palavra);

    LISTA* resp = clonarLista(&l); //obter o clonado
    inverter(resp); //inverter o clonado
    imprimirLista(resp); //imprimir o clonado -> oaic

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isac, o problema está no fato de na sua solução não ter sido criado, de fato, uma nova lista. Digo, através do Malloc.

Comment: @Caio_Ignatz Na sua lógica original também não tinha `malloc`, e por isso depreendi que queria inverter a lista que é recebida como parâmetro na função `inverter`, e não criar uma nova invertida. Mas não sei se estou a perceber corretamente o que está a dizer, tente ser um pouco mais especifico.

Comment: primeiro, preciso copiar a lista recebida. Segundo, preciso criar uma nova lista feita a partir da inversão da lista recebida. Não fui claro nesse ponto.

Comment: @Caio_Ignatz Já editei nesse sentido, calculei que fosse isso que queria devido à função de clonagem.

Comment: Funcionou, Isac. Muito obrigado mesmo! Você ajudou muito. Agora vou estudar seu código

Comment: @Caio_Ignatz Sem problema, bom estudo.